# Unittest for controller method which checks captcha in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, captcha

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 web application there is a method which checks the captcha from the web form. I use CaptchaMVC MVC5. This is how the method looks:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Foo(MyModel model){
    if(ModelState.IsValid){
        if(this.IsCaptchaValid("Error msg")){
            //do something
        }
    }
    var mod = this.GetMyModel();
    return this.View("Index", mod);
}
```

Now I want to write a unit test for this method. But then the captcha is unfortunately not valid. This is what my unit test currently looks like:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestFoo()
{
    var myMod = new MyModel();
    srvcModl.val1 = "0123456789";
    var controller = new MyController();

    var result = controller.foo(myMod);
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

Since the captcha is not valid, my test method also fails. Is there a way to set the captcha to valid in the test method?

Comment: We will need to see more relevant code to be able to advise on if a proper path can be arranged for the test. Tight now you have not provided enough details. Is `IsCaptchaValid` a function you control? If so, then please show it.

Comment: @Nkosi IsCaptchaValid is not a function I control. It is some kind of extension-method provided by CaptchaMvc5. As soon as I use the ```CaptchaMvc.HtmlHelpers``` namespace it is available in the controller instance.

Comment: I do not know which code I should provide you further. I need a way to set the captcha as valid in the test-method. But somehow I do not have access to it. Do you know a way to set the captcha-state to valid in the test-method?